# In the MB-lab character creator, viewport render and eevee turns pink, but works fine in cycles?

Tags: add-on, eevee-render-engine, error

In the Mb-Lab character creator, the viewport shading and Eevee render preview, render the character pink on the skin and all over except the eyes.

I set the character to Eevee engine in the creator:

[image]

Then in solid mode looks like this:

[image]

In viewport shading and Eevee render preview, it looks like this:

[image]

Finally in cycles render preview + denoiser, it looks like this:

[image]

If anyone can figure this out it would help a lot. Thx by the way it is blender 2.91 I'm using, but I also tested it in 3.0.

Comment: Hi :). I believe Eevee has lower limit for amount of textures in a material. Could that be the case?

Comment: If so, where is the setting in which I could change the limit? Because a lot of Youtube tutorials about this addon successfully have it rendered in Eevee.